# delete a clone from drop box in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have jquery drag-dop box to practice. i have no idea about how to delete the clone of an item from the drop box after drag the item.
my code for drag the the item...

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        //Counter
        counter = 0;
        //Make element draggable
        jQuery(".drag").draggable({
            helper:'clone',
            containment: 'frame',

            //When first dragged
            stop:function(ev, ui) {
              var pos=jQuery(ui.helper).offset();
              objName = "#clonediv"+counter
              jQuery(objName).css({"left":pos.left,"top":pos.top});
              jQuery(objName).removeClass("drag");


                 //When an existiung object is dragged
                jQuery(objName).draggable({
                  containment: 'parent',
                    stop:function(ev, ui) {
                      var pos=jQuery(ui.helper).offset();
                      //console.log($(this).attr("id"));
            //console.log(pos.left)
                        //console.log(pos.top)
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        //Make element droppable
        jQuery("#frame").droppable({
      drop: function(ev, ui) {
        if (ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag[0-9]/) != -1){
          counter++;
          var element=jQuery(ui.draggable).clone();
          element.addClass("tempclass");
          jQuery(this).append(element);
          jQuery(".tempclass").attr("id","clonediv"+counter);
          jQuery("#clonediv"+counter).removeClass("tempclass");

          //Get the dynamically item id
          draggedNumber = ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag([0-9])/)
          itemDragged = "dragged" + RegExp.$1
          //console.log(itemDragged)

          jQuery("#clonediv"+counter).addClass(itemDragged);
        }
          }
        });
    });

  </script>



<style id='flashfirebugstyle' type='text/css'>object,embed{visibility:hidden !important;}</style><script type='text/javascript'>window.addEventListener('load', function() {document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'object' || e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'embed'){try{FlashFirebug_init();}catch(e){}}}, false);try{FlashFirebug_init();}catch(e){}},false);</script></head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="options"><span><h2> Components</h2></span>
    <li id="drag1" class="drag">  
        <textarea name="" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>Text box<br>
    </li> <!-- end of drag1 -->
    <li id="drag2" class="drag">
    </li> <!-- end of drag2 -->
    <li id="drag3" class="drag">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />submit_button<br> 
    </li> <!-- end of drag3 -->
    <li id="drag4" class="drag">
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="radio-button"/> radio-button<br>  
    </li> <!-- end of drag4 -->
  </ul><!-- end of options -->
  <h2> Mockup Page</h2>
  <div id="frame">
    <span id="title">Drag here</span>
    <div id="tbldevs" > </div>
  </div><!-- end of frame -->
</div><!-- end of wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

how can i delete the item from the drop box.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand correctly your question : you want to delete elements that you have dropped previously in the droppable area?

If this is the point, you can have a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/YBPc4/ .

Once you have dropped an element, make a CTRL + click on it (but you can use any other event!), it will delete this element. This is done like this :

```
jQuery("#frame").delegate(".ui-draggable", "click", function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

The dropped elements are retrieved by the selector "ui-draggable" into the div "frame".